# Javascript Scope not setting global variables

Tags: javascript, scope

I have two functions, 1 of them push objects into an array. It calls another function which removes the key from the object and store only the values in the array.

However, it's not setting the expected result to the global array, with which I will work with the rest of my code.

```js
     var arr1 = [];
     
     function foo(callback){
      arr1.push({id: 1},{id: 2});
      console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1));
    
      callback(arr1);
     }
     
     foo(function(arr1){
      bar(arr1);
     });
    
    function bar(arr1){
     arr1 = arr1.map(x => x.id);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1));
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1)); // I want the result to be [1,2]
```

I can ignore the second function and put all it's contents into the first function, but that would make things messy, since in my actual codebase, the functions are quite complex. So is there any way to solve this?

Comment: This is exactly how it works since you're passing the value of the array to a local variable which gets updated. You can see what you should do instead here: https://jsfiddle.net/hkwg04py/

Comment: @BrettJeffreson But I have to pass the array in my case. Otherwise, it's of no use

Comment: why are you using the callback concept here. You can do it without them and make your code simple and achieve what you want just like what i have shown in my below answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to question your design - it sounds like you had to simplify some complex code already. While the other answers offer a working alternative solutions, it does not explain why.

JS parameters are not "out" - roughly translated to C, they are mere pointers, not pointers to pointers. If you replace the parameter value inside the function (which you did by `map` result), the modification stays inside the function scope. If you want to get the modification out of the function, apply any of the methods proposed by other answers:

- wrap the parameters-to-be-modified into a composite object
- make the modification a return value - either simply or in a temporary composite object
- make the modification a callback parameter

There is no way around it, really. JS has no syntax and no support for out parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use json object like this for isolate the scope without having "variable names" dependancy from your global scope.

```js
     var arr1 = {arr: []};
     
     function test1(callback){
      arr1.arr.push({id: 1},{id: 2});
      console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1.arr));
    
      callback(arr1);
     }
     
     test1(function(arr1){
      test(arr1);
     });
    
    function test(arr1){
     arr1.arr = arr1.arr.map(x => x.id);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1));
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1.arr)); // I want the result to be [1,2]
```

Comment: How comes that global `arr1` is modified by `test(arr1)` when "_JavaScript don't support parameters by reference_" ?

Comment: you have right, i correct the answer. I was thinking "for primitive" but is not this case. thks

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear is your code closure scopes and this may leads to problems in future, but if your design really needs such decision - here you can take working example

```js
var arr1 = [];
         
function test1(a, callback){
  a.push({id: 1},{id: 2});
  console.log('1', JSON.stringify(arr1));

  callback(a);
}

test1(arr1, function(a){
  test(a);
});

function test(a){
  //better do not use, but it works
  arr1 = a = a.map(x => x.id);
  console.log('2', JSON.stringify(a));
}

console.log('3', JSON.stringify(arr1)); // I want the result to be [1,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you make your code more simple and do something like below

```js
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];
     
function test1(arr){
  arr.push({id: 1},{id: 2});
  return arr;
}
   
function test(ar){
   ar = arr1.map(x => x.id);
   return ar;
}

var array1 = test(test1(arr1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(array1)); // I want the result to be [1,2]

var array2 = test(test1(arr2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(array2)); // I want the result to be [1,2]
```

Comment: What if there are more than 1 array? How would you write the `test1` then?

Comment: You mean to say you want to pass multiple arrays to `test1` and then push objects inside them & return and then the further process?

Comment: Yes. If there are multiple arrays, how would you return then?

Comment: Just put your arrays into an array and return it. `return [arr1, arr2];`

Comment: Then update your answer by including another array, and let me see if it's fulfilling my requirements.

Comment: What is your expected result if there are two arrays?

Comment: Expected results would be the same. Setting the 2 arrays into global scope.

Comment: Okay i have edited it. Is this you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a global variable, there is no point in passing it as parameter to other functions. You could do just this.

```
var arr1 = [];

     function test1(callback){
      arr1.push({id: 1},{id: 2});
      console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1));

      callback();
     }

     test1(function(){
        test();
     });

    function test(){
        arr1 = arr1.map(x => x.id);
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1));
```

You weren't actually replacing the value of the global variable `arr1` in `test()`, you were replacing the value of `arr1` that existed in the local scope of `test()`.

Comment: There is always a point in passing, like I said that the functions are complex and I have to work with the local variable in my function and set it to global.

Answer (score 0):

After making the array of json objects then you can write the below code to get array of id's it will work for you

```
var arr = [ {id: 1, data: "data1"},
                {id: 2, data: "data2"}];

var id_array = Object.keys(arr).map(function (k) {
                return arr[k]['id'].toString();
            });
```